# Duplicate google results

Tags: bug, google

Doing a search for `"Couldn't find" "_destroy" rails` gave both `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835422/rails-4-nested-attributes-couldnt-find-tag-with-id-for-person-with-id` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835422/rails-4-nested-attributes-couldnt-find-tag-with-id-for-person-with-id/19863805` in google's list of results.

[image]

I don't know whether it's Google's fault or Stack Exchange's fault, but I assume things working well is more important to Stack Exchange than to Google.

Comment: I don't see how this is *remotely* SE's problem.

Comment: @cat can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: It just... it's Google's job to serve results, and it's not really SE's fault if Google messes up. I don't see how this isn't a Google issue (and a very minor one)

Comment: @cat It may be Google's fault, or it may be SE's fault. But in terms of how big a problem it is, there's a huge asymmetry. If, hypothetically speaking, Google no longer returned Stack Exchange results, it'd affect Stack Exchange far more than it would affect Google.

Comment: It is IMHO very much SE's responsibility to add `<link rel="canonical" ... />` to the pages to avoid duplicates with linked answers etc., see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313471/384103